# Next.js cookies aren't coming through on router middleware

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, middleware

I'm attempting to create some route guarding using the new Next.Js 12 middleware feature. My authentication is based on a JWT token set on a cookie. I had previously implemented this using the API backend on Next.Js with no issues, and still when hitting the API routes the cookie will persist on the request no problem.

My issue appears when it will request a static page from the server. No cookies are attached so I can not determine if a User is authenticated and always redirect to a log in page. So for example the request to `http://localhost:3000/` (Homepage) will not send any cookies to the middleware. But, `http://localhost:3000/api/user` will send a cookie to the middleware. Is there a setting I have missed in the documentation to allow this to happen?

Not sure if at all helpful but here is my `_middleware.ts` file that sits on the root of the pages.

```js
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const middleware = (req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  console.log(req.cookies['user']);
  console.log(req.nextUrl.pathname);
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
    return NextResponse.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
  }
};

export default middleware;
```

Comment: can you share your _middleware.js code

Comment: @Yilmaz Not sure how helpful it is at the moment, kind of just debugging code but i've included it in the main question body now.

Comment: So the request to the homepage `/` will have cookie user undefined, but the request to `/api/user` will have a cookie attached to it.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same problem when redirecting to my Next app from Stripe Checkout.

Comment: @Ronald Blüthl- did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Next.js > 12.2

```
req.cookies.get("user")
```

Before Next.js 12.2,

```
req.cookies?.user
```

Comment: it dose not work  =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689900/why-middleware-is-not-synced-with-cookie

Comment: @ARSecond do u confirm that you set up the cookie correctly on the browser

Comment: Yes, This is a simple project with 4 pages. you can see the problem (this happens in the production not development.) https://github.com/darushHamidi/next-middleware

Comment: do you have envvriables in your project. maybe u did not set correctly for production

Comment: this is a small sample project and I did not use any env variables. if you see this small repo you will notice the problem. https://github.com/darushHamidi/next-middleware

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I use  tag for routing and it works but im not sure that it is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

**To check if the cookie exists**

```
request.cookies.has('YOUR_COOKIE_NAME')
```

**To get the cookie value**

```
request.cookies.get('YOUR_COOKIE_NAME')?.value
```