# How to access cookies in NextJS middleware

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, middleware

I've been working on some nextjs app and now I need to verify if user has a cookie to decide if he will be able to access the page or will he be redirected. I've setup middleware file, yet I'm unable to parse and get the cookie values. I've tried numerous options such as:

```js
export function middleware(request) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/nesto')) {
    // This logic is only applied to /nesto
    console.log(request.cookies);
  }
}
```

and

```js
export function middleware(req) {
  let cookie = req.cookies;
  console.log(cookie)
}
```

both fucntion return
`{ cookie: 'cookie=value; Path=/' }` yet I'm unable to parse them. I've tried using numerous libraries such as [Cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser), [Cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie), [Next-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-cookies)

i know that both of these functions don't verify anything, but for now i just want to be able to access cookies and their values and i know how to continue once i manage to accomplish so

Comment: there was a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449737/next-js-cookies-arent-coming-through-on-router-middleware/73575400#73575400

Comment: @Yilmaz i can't belive it was that easy,  thank you very much :)