# Why middleware is not synced with cookie

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have 4 routes(**Home**, **About**, **Contact**, **Admin**). If you want to visit the **admin** page first, you have to log in. After login, you can not visit the admin page,
you have to reload the page to be able to
visit it.

In the `middleware`, I check whether the cookie exists or not, if exists, you can visit the admin page otherwise you redirect to the **login page**

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if (request.cookies.get('user')?.value) return NextResponse.next()
    
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/admin/:path*',
}
```

Why do I have to reload the page after login?

It works in development mode perfectly (`npm run dev`).but the problem happens in production mode(`npm run build => npm run start`).

If you want to see the problem in action, [**Please clone this simple project**](https://github.com/darushHamidi/next-middleware)